# pause timer when audio is playing

Tags: android, audio, timer

i added "pause.Timer=true;" before the media player codes and  "pauseTimer=false;" after the media player codes but the app shows the timer still playing when audio is reading the question. the questions are simple problem sums questions. are my codes wrong?

These are my codes;

}.start();}

```
    private int getScore(){
        String scoreStr = scoreTxt.getText().toString();
        return Integer.parseInt(scoreStr.substring(scoreStr.lastIndexOf(" ")+1));
    }

    private void chooseQuestion(){
        answerTxt.setText("= ?");
        QnNum = random.nextInt(QnsList.length);

    final int DELAY_MS = 1000;


        question.setText("Qn "+(questionNumber));

        pauseTimer = true;

        qn = MediaPlayer.create(this, QnsList[QnNum]);
        qn.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer qn) {
            qn.stop();
            qn.reset();
            qn.release();
            qn = null;

        }
    });

        if (leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal == 0) {
            if (countDownTimer != null) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            }
            setTimer(originalTimerTimeInMilliSeconds);
        } else {
            if (countDownTimer != null) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            }
            setTimer(leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal);
        }

        pauseTimer = false;

        startTimer();

        qn.start();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I have no idea how your timer works, yet suggesting the solution.

Move  pauseTimer=false; inside onCompletionListener of MediaPlayer.

Ex:

```
  private void chooseQuestion(){
    answerTxt.setText("= ?");
    QnNum = random.nextInt(QnsList.length);

final int DELAY_MS = 1000;


    question.setText("Qn "+(questionNumber));

    pauseTimer = true;

    qn = MediaPlayer.create(this, QnsList[QnNum]);
    qn.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer qn) {
        qn.stop();
        qn.reset();
        qn.release();
        qn = null;
        pauseTimer = false;


    }
});

    if (leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal == 0) {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        setTimer(originalTimerTimeInMilliSeconds);
    } else {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
        setTimer(leftTimeInMillisecondsGlobal);
    }


    startTimer();

    qn.start();
```

}

Comment: I've tried to out the "pauseTimer = false" in but when i played the game, the timer is still running when the audio is saying the problem sums question. Am i missing any other codes or something?